# Untrack a certain folder via GIT

Tags: git

I don't want to track all the file inside my `account` folder

I've tried adding `/public/images/account/*`  to my `.gitignore` file

Every time, I did `git status` , I still get

`modified:   public/images/account/1001/logo.png`

What did I do wrong here ?

---

I've also tried adding `/public/images/account/*/logo.png` to `.gitignore`

Answer (score 1):

As you are being told that these files are `modified` that means that they have been added to the repo you also need to `forget` the files that you already added by using `git rm`

Comment: Or the `git rm` folder name ?

Comment: @ihue Yes - whichever you don't need - note that you should back up the files first just in case.

Comment: I see this `(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)`

Comment: I still see `modified:   public/images/account/1001/logo.png`

Comment: @¡hue a file once being added _and_ committed is never forgotten. So if you want to untrack it, you should remove it as @SteveBarnes wrote _and_ commit your changes. Then you may add `.gitignore` and it won't be shown anymore

Answer (score 0):

Once a file has been added (`git add`), `.gitignore` has no effect on it.

Removing a file from the cache (`git rm --cached`) will make it then being properly ignored if mentioned in `.gitignore`:

```
git rm --cached <files_to_remove>
git commit
```

However, the file removal action is stored by Git and will be applied every time the corresponding commit is replayed; and the file will still be present in previous commits. That is often an issue for files which should have never been added (IDE user-specific configuration files for instance) during merge, rebase, cherry-pick and so on. So, if modifying the history is acceptable, then the following solution is better:

```
# This action modifies the Git history! All commits previously containing the unwanted files will be rewritten.
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <files_to_remove>' HEAD
```